# How to add data to firebase database from android application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an android application that uses firebase for storing data. I want to add new data to the database without overwriting the exiting value.

My code

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_APP + "/id");
ref.child("Data").setValue(possibleValue);
```

I know this will overwrite the current value. I want to know how to use push() method. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Check the doc:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#basic_write)

> Using setValue() in this way overwrites data at the specified
>   location, including any child nodes.

You should use the push() method to generate a unique ID every time a new child is added to the specified Firebase reference.

Code (from the comments):

```
Person person = new Person(); //Adding values person.setName(name); 
person.setAddress(address); 
Firebase newRef = ref.child("Person").push(); 
newRef.setValue(person);
```

Comment: Can you post a sample code of using push() method?

Comment: Person person = new Person();
 //Adding values
 person.setName(name);
 person.setAddress(address);
 Firebase newRef = ref.child("Person").push();
 newRef.setValue(person);
Something like this try for this till the time i ll find complete example for you

Comment: Its working. Thank you so much.

Comment: Cheers Its my pleasure... Can I get an upvote from your side ?